# System View Full Qualification Ignored?

Tags: sql-server, system-tables

Why does full qualification appear to be getting ignored?

Here, I `USE` the database I'm querying, and get the expected results:

```
use [_DBMgt];
GO
select
    s.[name] as [Schema],
    o.[name] as [Table]
    from [_DBMgt].[sys].[objects] o
    inner join [_DBMgt].[sys].[schemas] s
        on s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
    where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.[object_id], N'IsUserTable') = 1
    order by s.[name], o.[name]
;
GO

Schema Table
------ ---------------
dbo    TableAbbrLookup

(1 row(s) affected)
```

Here, I did *not* `USE` the database I intend to query, but fully qualify the database reference; however, I am *not* getting the expected results.

```
use [master];
GO
select
    s.[name] as [Schema],
    o.[name] as [Table]
    from [_DBMgt].[sys].[objects] o
    inner join [_DBMgt].[sys].[schemas] s
        on s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
    where OBJECTPROPERTY(o.[object_id], N'IsUserTable') = 1
    order by s.[name], o.[name]
;
GO

Schema Table
------ ----------------------
sys    sqlagent_job_history
sys    sqlagent_jobsteps
sys    sqlagent_jobsteps_logs

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Either I'm expecting the wrong thing (likely) or I've found a bug (unlikely).

What am I missing?

Comment: OBJECTPROPERTY (Returns information about schema-scoped objects in the current database)

Comment: D'oh!  Thank you.  Missed that.  Repeatedly.

Comment: Instead of `OBJECTPROPERTY` try using `WHERE o.type = 'U'`

Comment: @Nic Agreed.  I was trying to go with a more modern and generalized approach, but the scope of `OBJECTPROPERTY()` precludes it, so I'm back to directly referencing columns and hard-coded values.  Thanks!

Comment: That would require the dev team to get to the point where they are focusing on that approach as well, rather than just new features (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation relating to [OBJECTPROPERTY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105(v=sql.110).aspx):

> Remarks
>
> The Database Engine assumes that object_id is in the current database
>   context. A query that references an object_id in another database will
>   return NULL or incorrect results. For example, in the following query
>   the current database context is the master database. The Database
>   Engine will try to return the property value for the specified
>   object_id in that database instead of the database specified in the
>   query. The query returns incorrect results because the view vEmployee
>   is not in the master database.